# How to return type Interface

Tags: java, interface, binary-tree

I am currently working on a project with a Binary tree and code for printing out a tree has been obtained from a repository.

Long story short it will printout in my desired format if I can implement an interface in my code.

However one of these requires an unusual return of an interface class. (see below)

```
@Override
public IBT getLeft() {

    return null;
}
```

This is the method for getting the left subtree where IBT is the Binary tree interface.

Is this simpler than I am making it?

Any help in returning Interfaces?

Comment: You need to return an object from a class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `getLeft` can return any class which implements `IBT` (if it is an interface) or extends `IBT` (if it is a class).

---

For example. Say I have the interface `Foo`, and two implementations, `Fizz` and `Buzz`:

```
public interface Foo { }

public class Fizz implements Foo {}
public class Buzz implements Foo {}
```

The `Fizz` and `Buzz` class can now be used in place of `Foo` because they implement the `Foo` interface.

Now say I have a method which requires I return `Foo` objects.

```
public interface Bar {
    Foo getFoo();
    Foo getAnotherFoo();
}
```

You can't directly create a `Foo` object because it is not a class. You can however use the `Fizz` and `Buzz` classes instead.

```
public class BarImpl implements Bar {
    @Override
    public Foo getFoo() {
        return new Fizz();
    }
    @Override
    public Foo getAnotherFoo() {
        return new Buzz();
    }
}
```

Comment: Managed to fix my problem, something causing me grief was Node in my BT was a sub class of Binary tree. I seperated the two into their own classes and all was good.

THank you everyone

Answer (score -1):

```
interface Foo{void display();}

public class TestFoo implements Foo
{void display(){System.out.println(“Hello World”);}

public static void main(String[] args){Foo foo = new TestFoo();foo.display();}}
```

I think this is helpful.

Comment: `TestFoo#display` needs to be `public` or else you get a compile error when assigning a weaker access privlege. You should also be using the `@Override` annotation